# meteor accounts-password server deploy error

Tags: macos, meteor, permissions, npm

I create meteor app then it can deploy to meteor.com server. but when I add accounts-password package, deployment to meteor server failed. deploy on localhost is working well without any error or warning message.

following is a copy from step to reproduce the error in my terminal.

```
Zaharuddins-MacBook-Pro:me zkhairuddin$ meteor create cdtest
Created a new Meteor app in 'cdtest'.         

To run your new app:                          
  cd cdtest                                   
  meteor                                      

If you are new to Meteor, try some of the learning resources here:
  https://www.meteor.com/learn                

Zaharuddins-MacBook-Pro:me zkhairuddin$ cd cdtest/
Zaharuddins-MacBook-Pro:cdtest zkhairuddin$ meteor deploy cdtest.meteor.com
Deploying to cdtest.meteor.com.               
Now serving at http://cdtest.meteor.com       
Zaharuddins-MacBook-Pro:cdtest zkhairuddin$ meteor add accounts-password

Changes to your project's package version selections:

accounts-base          added, version 1.2.1   
accounts-password      added, version 1.1.3
ddp-rate-limiter       added, version 1.0.0
email                  added, version 1.0.7
localstorage           added, version 1.0.5
npm-bcrypt             added, version 0.7.8_2
rate-limit             added, version 1.0.0
service-configuration  added, version 1.0.5
sha                    added, version 1.0.4
srp                    added, version 1.0.4


accounts-password: Password support for accounts
Zaharuddins-MacBook-Pro:cdtest zkhairuddin$ meteor deploy cdtest.meteor.com

/Users/zkhairuddin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1oxgk2a++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/zkhairuddin/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.build212220..0.7.8_2.11e8w98++os.linux.x86_64+os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova'
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/zkhairuddin/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1oxgk2a++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at /tools/fs/files.js:1331:28
    at Object.wrapper [as mkdir] (/tools/fs/files.js:1334:20)
    at Object.files.mkdir_p (/tools/fs/files.js:405:11)
    at new Builder (/tools/isobuild/builder.js:85:13)
    at [object Object]._.extend.saveToPath (/tools/isobuild/isopack.js:1144:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend._saveIsopack (/tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:366:15)
    at /tools/packaging/tropohouse.js:506:...blablabla
```

My meteor version is 1.2.0.2. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.meteor
```

This may fix your permission error.